# Writing to a text file within a loop - JAVA

Tags: java, html

I've got a loop that reads through a text file and outputs it, now I'm trying to get it to loop through, and write what's printed out into a text file as I want it to display as HTML. This is what I've got so far for this method:

```
public void hChoice()
        {
            File fbScores = new File ("P:/SD/Assignment1/fbScores.txt");
            String line = "";

            try {
                Scanner scanScores = new Scanner(fbScores);
                while(scanScores.hasNext())
                {
                    line = scanScores.nextLine();

                    stringArr = line.split(":");
                    if(stringArr.length == 4)
                    {

                        System.out.println("<h1>" + stringArr[0]+"    [" +stringArr[2]+"]    |" + stringArr[1]+"     ["+ stringArr[3]+" ]<br></h1>  ");

                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("P:/SD/Assignment1/HTMLscores.txt");
                        out.close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("problem " +e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

I've added the HTML tags in the print out and it prints it out fine, but I've tried several different methods to get it to print to a text file but none have worked. Pretty new to Java so any help would be much appreciated. Thankyou. :)

Comment: declare your PrintWriter next to your File declaration, then use it *instead of* `System.out`.  (I.E. change `System.out.println` to `out.println`

Comment: Have you tried using the PrintWriter out.println("this gets printed to the file")?

Comment: @Gus : Do you mean put PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("P:/SD/Assignment1/HTMLscores.txt"); underneath File fbScores = new File ("P:/SD/Assignment1/fbScores.txt");?

Comment: @David: No, I'll try that now :)

Comment: Neither will let me use just out.println for some reason, and I try declaring the PrintWriter beneath my initial filepath and it flags an error, being: Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

Comment: The method println(String) is undefined for the type readFile

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten your syntax and code wrong for writing to files.
Please Google and check the right syntax for writing to files using java. Plenty of resources available. You'll learn better if you try it yourself.

FYR, here is one: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_files_io.htm